# Only colour certain shapes in fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

Im creating an application where if a value goes over a certain threshold the top arrow will show whilst if it is below the threshold the bottom arrow will show. At the moment the only way I can think of doing this is to build two separate vertex and fragment shaders and only colour the correct triangle. Ideally I would like a way where I can put an if statement in my fragment shader that does this:

```
if (value > threshold)

colour top triangle / colour first 3 coordinates

else

colour bottom triangle / colour coordiantes 4-6
```

Is there a way of selecting the coordinates you want to colour?

Comment: You can always check for position values of a vertex in your shader code. Might not be the best solution but, you can check for your z coordinate of your arrows, maybe. Like, if(value > threshold && coord.z > someZValue) color the vertex etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work, it ended up with nothing showing on the screen.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking with coordinate system of Unreal environment. Check for y values, not z.